# git push でエラー Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github

git初学者です。MacBook Air os11.2.3を使用しています。
git pushするとエラーになり下記のメッセージが表示されます。

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

調べたところ秘密鍵をssh-addで追加する必要があるとのことでしたので
下記のようにしたのですが同じようなエラーになってしまいました。
ご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

```
Last login: Thu Apr  1 17:38:20 on ttys000
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "***@gmail.com"  
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/***/.ssh/id_ed25519): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/***/.ssh/id_ed25519.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/***/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:MyFrFYsM9jAWPHz7Xyh5ayfA8rvcgHlx2Aeg66dz23s ***@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|   oB.  o        |
|   o+*.o +       |
|     o*.+ .      |
|      .= + .     |
|      +oS.o..    |
|     o.o*=o..    |
|      +o+= o     |
|      .=o+= E    |
|      .o==+=     |
+----[SHA256]-----+
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 1687
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % open ~/.ssh/config
The file /Users/***/.ssh/config does not exist.
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % touch ~/.ssh/config
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Enter passphrase for /Users/***/.ssh/id_ed25519: 
Identity added: /Users/***/.ssh/id_ed25519 (***@gmail.com)
***@***noMacBook-Air ~ % cd ~/Documents/udemy_code/git_tutorial
***@***noMacBook-Air git_tutorial % git remote add origin https://github.com/***/git_tutorial.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
***@***noMacBook-Air git_tutorial % git push -u origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '52.192.72.89' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
***@***noMacBook-Air git_tutorial %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元で ssh の鍵ペアを生成した後、GitHub に公開鍵を登録する必要があります。

GitHub のドキュメントを参考に、ブラウザから公開鍵を登録してください：[GitHub アカウントへの新しい SSH キーの追加](https://docs.github.com/ja/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)。今回の質問の場合は `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` をアカウントに追加する必要があります。Mac の場合は以下でクリップボードにコピーできます。

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

また、ssh 接続ができていないのかリポジトリへの push 権限が無いのかを切り分けるために、ssh 接続ができる状態になっているのかだけをチェックすることができます：[SSH 接続をテストする](https://docs.github.com/ja/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection)

```sh
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ブラウザから公開鍵を登録しようとしたところ、「Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format」と表示されたのですが何が違ったのでしょうか。

Comment: まず、登録しようとしているものが本当に公開鍵になっているかをご確認ください。秘密鍵と取り違えることがよくあります（取り違えていた場合、今の鍵ペアは削除し、鍵ペアを生成するところからやり直してください）。

Comment: 失礼しました、クリップボードにコピーしたところ無事登録できました。